# To express $f(x,z)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha n^2 x+\beta n z}}{n!}$ as known functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, special-functions

$\alpha,\beta >0$
$$f(x,z)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha n^2 x+\beta n z}}{n!}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial z}=\beta \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha n^2 x+\beta n z}}{(n-1)!}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial z}|_{z=2 \frac{ \alpha}{\beta} x+ z_1}=\beta \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha n^2 x+\beta n (2 \frac{ \alpha}{\beta} x+  z_1)}}{(n-1)!}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial z}|_{z=2 \frac{ \alpha}{\beta} x+ z_1}=\beta e^{\alpha x+ \beta z_1} \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha (n-1)^2 x+\beta (n-1) z_1}}{(n-1)!}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial z}|_{z=2 \frac{ \alpha}{\beta} x+ z_1}=\beta e^{\alpha x+ \beta z_1} \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha n^2 x+\beta n z_1}}{n!}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial z}|_{z=2 \frac{ \alpha}{\beta} x+ z_1}=\beta e^{\alpha x+ \beta z_1} f(x,z_1)$$

I do not know how to solve this kind  differential equations.

Do you know how to solve that?

Can we express the function as known functions such as [Jacobi Theta Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) etc?

Also  could you please share your knowledge about the function if you know it.

Thanks a lot for answers

EDIT:

Another property is:

$$-\alpha\frac{\partial^2{f(x,z)}}{\partial z^2}=\beta^2 \frac{\partial{f(x,z)}}{\partial x} $$

Comment: If $\alpha=0$, things would have been easy. Even the $\beta=0$ case does not seem to admit an easy expression...

Comment: You may assume $\beta=1$. Put $z:=is$ and think of $x$ as "time". Then your $f$ solves the heat equation (look at your edit!) for  $s\in {\mathbb R}/(2\pi)$ with initial condition $f(0,i s)=\exp(e^{is})$. Theta functions would result from simpler initial conditions, like a $\delta$-function.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter :If so, Which initial conditions are required to get the function above? Thanks

Comment: @Mathlover: As I said: Putting $x=0$ ($x$ is time!) in the definition of your $f$ gives $$f(0,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(e^{\beta z})^n\over n!}=\exp(e^{\beta z})\ .$$

Comment: @Christian Blatter: But since heat equation can only be solved by using separation of variables to construct kernel form solutions, which will return to the original summation form and no help.

Comment: @Mathlover: Your question does not design well. Why you need $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? $x$ and $z$ just taken the roles of independent variables, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ become redundant and should be merged with $x$ and $z$ respectively.

Comment: At least http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html cannot find this type of infinite series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\alpha$ and $x$ , $\beta$ and $z$ are both taking the same roles in $f(x,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\alpha n^2x+\beta nz}}{n!}$ and should be burdensome. So you should simplify your definition to $f(x,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$ , where $x\geq0$ .

$f(x,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$ can create the following differential equation:

$\dfrac{df(x,z)}{dz}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{ne^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{ne^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+zn}}{(n-1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-x(n+1)^2+z(n+1)}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+(z-2x)n+z-x}}{n!}=e^{z-x}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+(z-2x)n}}{n!}=e^{z-x}f(x,z-2x)$

Note that this is a DDE. Unfortunately even the forms of the general solutions of DDEs we still can't know well, we can't know the number of I.C.s should be required. So this approach fails.

$f(x,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$ can create the following PDE:

$\dfrac{\partial^2f(x,z)}{\partial z^2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^2e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$

$\dfrac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{-n^2e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial^2f(x,z)}{\partial z^2}=0$

Note that the form of the general solution of this PDE is as follows:

Let $f(x,z)=X(x)Z(z)$ ,

Then $X'(x)Z(z)+X(x)Z''(z)=0$

$X'(x)Z(z)=-X(x)Z''(z)$

$-\dfrac{X'(x)}{X(x)}=\dfrac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{X'(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2\\Z''(z)-s^2Z(z)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}X(x)=c_3(s)e^{-xs^2}\\Z(z)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sinh zs+c_2(s)\cosh zs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1z+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore f(x,z)=C_1z+C_2+\int_sC_3(s)e^{-xs^2}\sinh zs~ds+\int_sC_4(s)e^{-xs^2}\cosh zs~ds$ or $C_1z+C_2+\sum\limits_sC_3(s)e^{-xs^2}\sinh zs+\sum\limits_sC_4(s)e^{-xs^2}\cosh zs~ds$

It is clear that two I.C.s should be required to solve this PDE uniquely, however from the functional property itself, only $f(0,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{zn}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(e^z)^n}{n!}=e^{e^z}$ is trivially known, others for example $f(x,0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2}}{n!}$ cannot be trivially known.

So we still no hope to express $f(x,z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xn^2+zn}}{n!}$ as known functions.